# How can I export a string from an array in props instead of one value at a time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning ReactJS and I am building a color randomizer, tutorial is using plain text i.e. "purple, blue" , but i want to take a step further and make Hex strings values for the color, the problem I cant solve is how to export a string made up from elements in an array in my props, currently I am able to export 1 elements at a time, and have to call the function six times in order to make a hex value.

This is my function that exports one value:

```
    function choice(arr){
    let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
    return arr[randomIndex];

}


export {choice};
```

This is my component that reads the value, and as you can see, I am calling it six times:

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {choice} from './helpers'
import './Box.css'
import './helpers'

class Box extends Component{
    static defaultProps = {
        colorHex : ['a','b','c','d','e','f','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0']
    }
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {color: `#${choice(this.props.colorHex)}${choice(this.props.colorHex)}${choice(this.props.colorHex)}${choice(this.props.colorHex)}${choice(this.props.colorHex)}${choice(this.props.colorHex)}`};
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
    }
    pickColor(){
        let newColor = choice(this.props.colorHex);
    }
    handleClick(){

    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div className="Box" style={{backgroundColor: this.state.color}}onclick={this.handleClick}>

            </div>
        )
    }
}


export default Box;
```

As you can see, I am working on a click event that randomizes the colors on click (didnt get there yet, have to cross this first).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a loop in the choice function

```
function choice(arr){
  let hexString = ''
  for (let i = 0; i<=6; i++) {
    let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
    hexString += arr[randomIndex]
  }
  return hexString;
}


export {choice};
```

This returns a string like '123abc'

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this.

```
function choice(arr){
 let str = "";
 let randomIndex;
 for (i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
  randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
  str += arr[randomIndex];
 }
 return str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the randomIndex 6 times in the choice function itself using for loop.

```
 function choice(arr){
     let t = '';
     for(let i=0;i<6;i++){
         t += arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)]
     }
    let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
    return t;

}
arr =  ['a','b','c','d','e','f','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0']
```